# "So that" or "For ... to"

Tags: to-for

Does "so that" and "for ... to" have the same usage?

For example:

> I bought this sweater **so** (**that**) you can wear it.

and:

> I bought this sweater **for** you **to** wear it.

Is there any difference between the two expressions or do they have the same meaning?

Comment: _For ... to_ is just the marker of an infinitive: _for_ precedes the subject noun phrase (if there is one), and _to_  precedes the infinitive verb phrase. Most infinitives at the end of the sentence can be understood as a "purpose infinitive", and this is true in the sentence you give. _So that_ is another way of introducing a purpose clause, but it is not at all the same as using an infinitive; _that_ has to be followed by a complete tensed clause.

Comment: They are virtually identical in meaning. The first sounds a little more emphatic in its emphasis 'so that you could wear it'.

Comment: Just commenting on the second sentence, in idiomatic UK English we would just say "I bought this sweater for you to wear." The "it" is superfluous.

Comment: Both your sentences use an adverb dependent clause to modify the verb *bought.* In the first you can actually write *so that* because it is a conjunction, and it means —used to introduce a clause that states a reason or purpose-- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that  || the other adverb clause with the conjunction *for* means : for the reason that, or because, which is different from the first sentence because you bought the sweater only because you want the person to wear it; it’s like if the person doesn’t wear it, you take it back to the store. So it’s like a command.

Comment: These are different grammatical constructions, the first a subordinate clause introduced by the conjunction "so that", and the second an infinitive  , both having approximately the same meaning. I think what makes these sentences a little different is "can" in the first phrase.

Comment: The second sentence is, at least non-ideomatic if not grammatically incorrect. We would say "I bought this sweater for you to wear" not "I bought this sweater for you to wear _it_".

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me in your example "so that" is a form of rationalization or persuasion. "You may wear it, but you don't have to."

"For ... to" is more of a command or a direct instruction such as "You will wear this sweater because I bought it for you."

Let's try a different example:

**Jodi made coffee so that she would stay awake.**

**Jodi made coffee for herself to stay awake.**

Here, The first example is a rationalization. "There are many ways to stay awake, but Jodi chose to make coffee.

The second example is a direct instruction. "The way for Jodi to stay awake is to drink coffee."

Semantics? The explanation above regarding emphasis makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Their meanings and distributions overlap, but not totally.

**so that**

(1) Indicates purpose, necessary condition; in order that, with the result that.

> He must die **so that** others might live.
>
> He must die **for** others **to** live.

Indicates purpose, intent; in such a way that, with the intent that.

> He tied a complex knot **so that** others would find it hard to undo.
>
> *He tied a complex knot **for** others **to** find hard to undo.

(Based on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_that).)

There are other similar-looking usages:

> He left the dirty dishes for others to wash <==?==> He left the dirty
>   dishes, so that others had to do the washing up.

Answer (score 0):

They seem synonymous. If you can tease out a difference, it's subtle. If you removed the "it" from the "for" sentence, then there would be a more apprecable difference. "So" would speak more to 'why I did it', and "for" would explain 'what the sweater is for'.